# Generate list from values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to generate a list of keys and values in the following format:

```
l = [('document_1 ':'abc'), ('document_2': 'cde'), ('document_3': 'def')... ]
```

The data I have is:

```
document_1 = "abc"
document_2 = "cde"
document_3 = "def"
documents = [document_1, document_2, document_3, document_4, document_5]
```

I know I can do this with a dictionary comprehension but I need it in a list format and I don't know how to do it. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
documents = ["abc", "cde", "def"]
print([{f"document_{i}": doc} for i, doc in enumerate(documents, start=1)])
```

Output:

```
[{'document_1': 'abc'}, {'document_2': 'cde'}, {'document_3': 'def'}]
```